# fetch the value of selected data-attribute from multiple possibilities using jQuery js

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an html page containing similar selection boxes, each being unique in two attributes:

1. `data-behavior="result_selection_XXX"`
2. `id="some_unique_id`

now, I want to catch an event that happens in any one of the `data-behavior` elements,
and then get the `XXX` value or its `id` so I can further process it.

So, using Coffeescript I started with:

```
jQuery ->
    $("[data-behavior^=result_selection_]").change ->
        selected_val = ....
```

How can this be achieved efficiently?
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `selected_val = $(this).attr('id');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("[data-behavior^=result_selection_]")
.change(function(e) {
  selected_val = $(e.target).data("behavior").slice(-3); // `XXX` value
    console.log(selected_val);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s8erf7je/

Comment: Works beautifully! thanks!
If my XXX is not 3-chars long, how would you fetch it using regex?

Comment: @cyber101 Try `selected_val = $(e.target).data("behavior").split("_")[2];`  http://jsfiddle.net/s8erf7je/1/

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to use the global listeners of JQuery, so something like:

```
$("body").on("change", "[data-behavior^=result_selection_]", {}, handler)
```

This is in JS, I am not familiar with Coffeescript to write the above code in that.

More documentation : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This works as well, but the above solutions are little more readable in my opinion.

Comment: As far as I can see, your question was "How can this be achieved efficiently? Is there a better way of doing this?". What the above answer is doing is exactly same as what you are doing.

Comment: And obviously the above solution is very limited.